# The treatments are collectively not significant but one of the treatment is significant

Tags: categorical-data, blocking

I am confused to interpret this kind of data.
[image]

The `Avg_Treatment` is collectively not significant since the P-value is 0.094, bigger than the significance level 0.05.

However, from the coefficient table

[image]

The Treatment 1 is significantly different, but the others are not. How can I interpret this kind of data? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From table 2, you can see that coefficients for Treatment 1 (T1) and Treatment 2,3 (T2, T3) have a different sign (negative and positive). This says that T1 has a negative effect on your dependent variable and T2, T3 have a positive effect. What you are doing next, you combine all treatments together and hence the effects cancel each other.

Think about longevity and you want to test whether morning exercises and smoking affect longevity. Individually both of these factors have an effect on longevity, but in the opposite directions (smoking - negative, exercises - positive). Now if you combine them you might not find any effect, since the person improves health and then damages it.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @Woden, you are welcome!